# Comparing values in excel over an array in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

So I have two sheets. One has a revision letters in column H, whilst the other has columns with the revisions being used. So every third column (Starting at E then H, K, N etc.) has the about 400 rows of revisions to compare against.

How it works, I check column E of EMP against to see if the rows match cell H2 of SOPs. If it doesnt then I colour the cells Yellow. Then I move on to Column H of EMP and check against cell H3 of SOPs. This continues on.

However I found that for some reason it doesnt always get it right, say cell H2 of SOPs is revison B. Now in Column E it might colour in some rows with B and some not.

Here is the code im using:

```
Sub CompareRevisionsAndHighlight()
Dim SOPsSheet As Worksheet
Dim EMPSheet As Worksheet
Dim SOPsRow As Long
Dim EMPColumn As Range
Dim EMPCell As Range
Dim ColumnIndex As Variant

' Set references to the SOPs and EMP sheets
Set SOPsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOPs")
Set EMPSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EMP")

' Initialize the SOPs row counter
SOPsRow = 2 ' Start from H2

' Array of column offsets (E, H, K, N, etc.)
Dim ColumnOffsets As Variant
ColumnOffsets = Array(5, 8, 11, 14) ' Adjust as needed

' Loop through each column offset in the array
For Each ColumnIndex In ColumnOffsets
    ' Set the EMP column range based on the offset
    Set EMPColumn = EMPSheet.Cells(1, ColumnIndex).Resize(400, 1)
    
    ' Loop through each cell in the EMP column
    For Each EMPCell In EMPColumn
        ' Get the current revision from SOPs sheet (in the current SOPs row)
        SOPsRevision = SOPsSheet.Cells(SOPsRow, "H").Value
        
        ' Compare the revisions
        If Not IsEmpty(EMPCell.Value) And EMPCell.Value <> SOPsRevision Then
            ' If they don't match and the EMP cell is not blank, make it yellow
            EMPCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End If
        
        ' Increment the SOPs row counter
        SOPsRow = SOPsRow + 1
    Next EMPCell
Next ColumnIndex
End Sub
```

I added a photo to show what I mean:

[image: Example]

Comment: Probably has a space in the cell, try using `...And Trim(EMPCell.Value) <> Trim(SOPsRevision)`. Why do you change the search cell? Wasn't it supposed to look in the entire range for H2's  value and a different column for H3?

Comment: In your first paragraph it would be useful to add the sheet names (SOPs/EMP) so the second paragraph is easier to follow....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is comparing E1 vs H2, E2 vs H3 ... It is different with the comparing logic.

Base on the logic from OP.

> How it works, I check column E of EMP against to see if the rows match cell H2 of SOPs. If it doesnt then I colour the cells Yellow. Then I move on to Column H of EMP and check against cell H3 of SOPs. This continues on.

Comparing column against cell H2 of SOPs, `SOPsRow = SOPsRow + 1` should be moved to below `Next EMPCell`.

Updated code is marked with `**update**`.

```
    ' Loop through each column offset in the array
    For Each ColumnIndex In ColumnOffsets
        ' Set the EMP column range based on the offset
        Set EMPColumn = EMPSheet.Cells(1, ColumnIndex).Resize(400, 1)
    
        ' Get the current revision from SOPs sheet (in the current SOPs row)
        SOPsRevision = SOPsSheet.Cells(SOPsRow, "H").Value  ' **update**
        ' Loop through each cell in the EMP column
        For Each EMPCell In EMPColumn
        
            ' Compare the revisions
            If Not IsEmpty(EMPCell.Value) And EMPCell.Value <> SOPsRevision Then
                ' If they don't match and the EMP cell is not blank, make it yellow
                EMPCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            End If
        
        Next EMPCell
        ' Increment the SOPs row counter
        SOPsRow = SOPsRow + 1  ' **update**
    Next ColumnIndex
```